# Is my NNID region locked?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

Maybe my question is a little dumb, but better be safe than sorry!

Currently I own an American region 3DS, but, I moved and I am now living in Europe.

In the sad event that I need to buy a new 3DS, for me be able to do a system transfer from my old 3DS to my new one so I don't lose my games, DLCs and softwares (like my pokebank account), do I need my new 3DS to be american too?

I was thinking I could just use system transfer to the new European console and re-download my bought titles back at this new European 3DS, but I'm afraid now so it's better to ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is best to contact Nintendo support.  The systems themselves are region locked but I don't know if they can transfer your NNID to a different region so you can buy games in the new region.

Comment: However, I recently was able to purchase from the Canadian store while in Hong Kong, so their region locking doesn't really stop you from buying stuff online.   You can always just import a North American 3DS and just go from there.

Comment: @TimmyJim that's about the console itself, while this is about the account, I believe, so I don't think it's a dupe.

Comment: From what @Nelson said then, worst case cenario I would need to import an american 3DS. But can someone give a 100% sure that you can't perform system transfer from an american 3DS to an european 3DS? (Even if possible, Im still afraid if my games will be available or not, nintendo is always a headache region locking all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apparently, yes.**

[Nintendo Enthusiast reports](http://nintendoenthusiast.com/news/nintendo-network-id-will-region-lock-3ds-eshop-games/):

> Nintendo UK has released a new FAQ on the Nintendo Network ID on the
>   3DS, essentially explaining that it will region lock eShop games on
>   the system.
>
> This happens because of two things. One, once the 3DS is registered to
>   an NNID, it will keep that region setting for that particular ID, and
>   you will no longer be allowed to change it for that 3DS. Two, if you
>   did have multiple regions for games and amounts left over in multiple
>   currencies, the currencies not in your region will be eliminated.

The [European Nintendo](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/Nintendo-3DS-Family/Instant-Software/Nintendo-Network-ID/FAQ/Nintendo-Network-ID-FAQ-828876.html) site is cryptic in how it is explained.

Comment: Seriously with the currency? You simply lose money because of a system restriction they made?

Comment: I wouldn't have posted it as part of the answer if it wasn't fact.